# Wordpress MySQL: copy fields from tables (commentmeta and comments) to new table

Tags: mysql, wordpress

**The background:**

- Table *wp_commentmeta* contains columns: *country*, *city*, *continent* and *comment_id*.
- Table *wp_comments* contains columns: *comment_ID*, *comment_post_ID* and *user_id*.
- I custom created a table named *wp_combined* with columns: *country*, *city*, *continent* and *user_id*.

I would like to copy country, city, continent, user_id and comment_post_ID to the newly custom created table wp_combined. This requires to associate the wp_commentmeta fields of country, city and continent with the user_id and comment_post_ID in wp_comments.

**My code so far:**

```
USE wp_database;
INSERT into wp_combined (country, city, continent, comment_post_id, user_id)     
                        /* note above are the only fields required to copy) */
SELECT country, city, continent, comment_post_id, user_id FROM wp_commentmeta, wp_comments
```

How can I do this? Thank you, friends.